# What is the best approch to send data to its descendant in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

FOr example I have one parent component ( i'll call it animal)
and several child components (dog, cat, horse) and child's child components (Collie, English Foxhound, Fox Terrier, German Shepherd Dog). If i wanna send a function from animal to Collie, i have to send this function to Dog component and from Dog to Collie and only after 2 props i will be able to use this function in Collie component. Is there any better approch to send a function from animal directly to Collie ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others on top the new Context API that was introduced in the new versions of react maybe different in react versions and still not recommended for just avoid passing props a fewer levels down in the component tree.

The component composition is a better option if you don't want to use redux which maybe complex for less usage like this example.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context

You basically create your parent component in this case `<Animal/>` to expected children nodes, `<Dog />`as well to expect children then you can later on pass it `<Collie />` with the props.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Context API.
Read more at the official docs : https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Basically, you define a context value and pass it with a Provider, which can be accessed by any node within the child tree.

Do note that the Context API is different for different versions of React and may change in future. You may also use Redux and react-redux for state management which would be internally using the context api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Context API which is now official. More information as to how to use this can be found here - https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-the-new-react-context-api-fce011e7d87

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take a look at React "[Component Composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)" pattern (docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). It is pretty straightforward and doesn't have a reusability issue that sometimes might occur in with React Context.

Ta-ta